# Trying to name multiple indexes getting Key error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Good morning,

I'm using python 3.6. I'm trying to name my index (see last line in code below) because I plan on joining to another DataFrame. The DataFrame should be multi-indexed. The index is the first two columns ('currency' and 'rtdate') and the data

```
                      rate
   AUD  2010-01-01    0.897274
        2010-02-01    0.896608
        2010-03-01    0.895943
        2010-04-01    0.895277
        2010-05-01    0.894612
```

This is the code that I'm running:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

df=pd.read_csv('file.csv',index_col=0)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
new_index = pd.date_range(df.index.min(),df.index.max(),freq='MS')
df=df.reindex(new_index)
df=df.interpolate().unstack()
rate = pd.DataFrame(df)
rate.columns = ['rate']
rate.set_index(['currency','rtdate'],drop=False)
```

Running this throw's an error message:

```
KeyError: 'currency'
```

What am I missing.

Thanks for the assistance

Comment: So I made the changes you suggested and I get a new error:

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-372383d8827b> in <module>()
      7 new_index = pd.date_range(df.index.min(),df.index.max(),freq='MS')
      8 df=df.reindex(new_index)
----> 9 rate = df.interpolate().unstack().set_axis(('currency','rtdate')).reset_index()

TypeError: set_axis() missing 1 required positional argument: 'labels'

Comment: I found that if I replaced set_axis() with rename_axis that I no longer got the error. Thanks jezreal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the names of the levels of `MultiIndex` by using [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) first and then [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for columns from `MultiIndex`:

So you'd end up with this:

```
rate = df.interpolate().unstack().set_axis(('currency','rtdate')).reset_index()
```

instead of this:

```
df=df.interpolate().unstack()
rate = pd.DataFrame(df)
rate.columns = ['rate']
rate.set_index(['currency','rtdate'],drop=False)
```